# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error on same domain

Tags: php, jquery

My page has been working for a while now, and all of a sudden its giving me this cross domain request error. The odd thing is I am making a relative request to the file so I do not see why I am getting this.

Error:

OPTIONS https://www.aliahealthcare.com/php/central.php?logout=true 
Origin https://aliahealthcare.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

send jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
logout aliahealthcare.com/:841
picker aliahealthcare.com/:901
(anonymous function) aliahealthcare.com/:713
f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
h.handle.i jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.aliahealthcare.com/php/central.php?logout=true.

Origin https://aliahealthcare.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. aliahealthcare.com/:1

Code:

```
 function logout (){

      $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/php/central.php",
                   data: { logout: 'true' },
                   success: function(msg) {
                     if(msg=='1'){ 

                     location.reload();

                    } 
                    else if(msg=='0') {
                        alert("Logout Failed! Please try again!") 
                    }
                  },
                  error:function(msg){
                    alert("Error"+msg);
                    }

         });
     }
```

Result when outputting result of ajax:

`Object {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function (a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}
always: function (){i.done.apply(i,arguments).fail.apply(i,arguments);return this}
complete: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
done: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
error: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
fail: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return s===2?n:null}
getResponseHeader: function (a){var c;if(s===2){if(!o){o={};while(c=bG.exec(n))o[c[1].toLowerCase()]=c[2]}c=o[a.toLowerCase()]}return c===b?null:c}
isRejected: function (){return!!i}
isResolved: function (){return!!i}
overrideMimeType: function (a){s||(d.mimeType=a);return this}
pipe: function (a,b,c){return f.Deferred(function(d){f.each({done:[a,"resolve"],fail:[b,"reject"],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b[1],g;f.isFunction(c)?i[a](function(){g=c.apply(this,arguments),g&&f.isFunction(g.promise)?g.promise().then(d.resolve,d.reject,d.notify):d[e+"With"](this===i?d:this,[g])}):i[a](d[e])})}).promise()}
progress: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
promise: function (a){if(a==null)a=h;else for(var b in h)a[b]=h[b];return a}
readyState: 0
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: function (a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this}
state: function (){return e}
status: 0
statusCode: function (a){if(a){var b;if(s<2)for(b in a)j[b]=[j[b],a[b]];else b=a[v.status],v.then(b,b)}return this}
statusText: "error"
success: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
then: function (a,b,c){i.done(a).fail(b).progress(c);return this}
__proto__: Object`

Comment: `http://blahblah.com` is different from `http://www.blahblah.com` in terms of cross-domain policy.

Comment: @phpisuber01 It shouldn't matter, it's still a relative path, implying the request would use the origin domain.

Comment: @BradM Agreed, but his Options/Origin information would suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Osman Can you do like `var jqXhr = $.ajax('your settings here');` and then post the results of `console.log(jqXHR)`. Perhaps you have some conflict setting in `$.ajaxSetup()`

Comment: ok I will do that and post

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the URLs is the "www.", and I think that's enough to trigger "cross-domain". You're right that it's strange for a relative request to result in a dissimilar URL; perhaps it's something to do with JQuery's ajax method. You may be able to quickly fix the issue by either entering in the full hostname manually, or determining it with `window.location`

Comment: I do not want to hard code the name to allow for users to use the www subdomain with the same code.

Comment: Then you can go the second route. window.location.host (or .hostname) will give you everything between the http:// and the next slash. Here on SO, it's "stackoverflow.com". On Google, it's "www.google.com". We use it often for our webapp, which will often run on different servers.